# Paypal IPN's payment status

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I set up a recurring payment within my website. Of course Paypal is the payment method.

So, when a customer have an **empty paypal account**, the automatic payment will not be performed.

In this case what's the value of **payment_status** field ?

And how can I identify the failure of payment ?

Comment: This is all answered in the IPN documentation. Zero research effort shown.

Answer (score 2):

The docs for IPN are [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/).
Per the docs:

> payment_status == The status of the payment:
>   **Canceled_Reversal**: A reversal has been canceled. For example, you won a dispute with the customer, and the funds for the transaction that was reversed have been returned to you.
>
> **Completed**: The payment has been completed, and the funds have been added successfully to your account balance.
>
> **Created**: A German ELV payment is made using Express Checkout.
>
> **Denied**: The payment was denied. This happens only if the payment was
>   previously pending because of one of the reasons listed for the
>   pending_reason variable or the Fraud_Management_Filters_x variable.
>
> **Expired**: This authorization has expired and cannot be captured.
>
> **Failed**: The payment has failed. This happens only if the payment was
>   made from your customer's bank account.
>
> **Pending**: The payment is pending. See pending_reason for more
>   information.
>
> **Refunded**: You refunded the payment.
>
> **Reversed**: A payment was reversed due to a chargeback or other type of
>   reversal. The funds have been removed from your account balance and
>   returned to the buyer. The reason for the reversal is specified in the
>   ReasonCode element.
>
> **Processed**: A payment has been accepted.
>
> **Voided**: This authorization has been voided.